# Show that $R$ is a partial order.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $\sum = \{a, b\}$. $\sum^*$ is the set of all words of any length. Define $R \subseteq\sum^* \times \sum^*$ as follows:

$(w, v) \in R \ \text{if there exists} \ z \in\sum^* \ \text{such that} \ v = wz.$

Show that $R$ is a partial order.

I understand that it's both reflexive and anti-symmetric but I'm struggling to mathematically show the proofs for it.

Reflexivity: $w = wz \ for \ (w, w) \ where \ z = \lambda$  (where $\lambda$ is the empty word.)

Antisymmetry: $v = wz \ \text{if and only if} \ z = \lambda \ \text{and } v = w$

How do I formally prove this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is $\lambda$ for example?

Comment: It's the empty word.

Comment: What is $\Sigma^*$?  Is it the set of words with alphabet $\Sigma$?

Comment: Set of all words of any length, including 0. The asterisk represents the length of the words in the set.

Comment: What you wrote for anti-symmetry does not concern anti-symmetry. You're also missing transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Antisymmetry.  Assume uRv and vRu.
Thus exists x,y with v = ux and u = vy
Show u = uxy and take it from there.